# Laravel - Executing multiple requests after a while

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Im working on a delivery app, and it has a feature where the client can pick a schedules date + time for the delivery to be sent to the delivery agents, and i was thinking what would be the best way to handle this, so when a new delivery is made, a date + time is given (if its null, then the delivery will be triggered immediately and sent to the delivery agents), and many delivery requests can be made at once, so i was thinking in terms of performance on the server side, and i would like to optimize this, and also mind the fact that if i had a large number of scheduled delivery requests, they all have to be sent at the right time (not late).

Would Laravel's Task scheduling be enough for this (reading from documentation now) ? i create an artisan command (+ run it each 30 minutes for example) which would check the date + time and if the conditions are met, it sends the delivery, else, it continues to the next one ? this kinda worried me in case there was a large number of requests.

Should i run multiple ones ? or perhaps there is a much more suitable solution to this ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The scheduler would be appropriate to dispatch all due deliveries and those dispatched jobs can be handled by one or more queue workers. [More info on queues](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues)

Comment: @apokryfos so i basically dispatch a delivery request regardless of when it should be triggered ? say for example i have 100 requests that need to be executed after 2 days, would it be okay to dispatch all 100 and wait for the execution until that day ?

Comment: Ok there's 2 options here really: (a) [delayed dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#delayed-dispatching) where you'd dispatch the job when it's received and only run it when it's scheduled or (b) run a scheduled task every minute that dipatches all jobs that are meant to be dispatched at that time. Personally I don't think the first approach is reliable for very long delays because it relies on your cache which you might accidentally (or delibarately) clear. The reason I suggest for your scheduled task to dipsatch jobs is because you can fine tune your queue handler instances

Comment: @apokryfos actually you are right, i can run a scheduled task every minute or 30 minutes perhaps and try an optimize the process

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of using the command and scheduling it, I think you need to add a job inside the command and queue the delivery requests.

Comment: Queuing the requests was my initial idea, but i was worried that queuing 10000 requests mind cause some deliveries to be triggered after their scheduled time, or is that just a misunderstanding on my end ?

Comment: you can increase the number of workers in order to do requests sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd save all deliveries in a table with a target execute time (or null if it's now). Then run a custom command through scheduler every minute that goes something like this:

```
    // get all deliveries where execute_time is null or in the past
    $deliveries = Delivery::whereNull('execute_time')->orWhere('execute_time', '<', Carbon::now())->where('executed', false)->get();

    // send deliveries to job queue
    foreach ($deliveries as $delivery) {
        dispatch(new SendDelivery($delivery));
    }
```

SendDelivery will be a job that sends out the notifications I guess, start multiple queue workers so everything gets done faster.

Comment: Yes thats what im going with, all deliveries are saved on tables naturally, the question was whats the best method to go through the records, and im now looking at Task Scheduling documentation